# Exception thrown even though I'm catching it

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to enumerate a collection URLs to get corresponding spotify tracks using [Spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#installation).
When a track ID does not exist, the program throws an error, even though I'm catching the exact error mentioned. The error says that during handling of the exception another exception occured, does this mean I've setup my try catch incorrectly?

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="...",
                                               client_secret="...",
                                               redirect_uri="http://localhost/",
                                               scope="playlist-modify-public",
                                               requests_timeout=5))
try:
    track = sp.track('7IaxPh0ttHTsJ4rVPPiQ9V', 'NL')
except sp.SpotifyException:
    x = 0
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Exception has occurred: SpotifyException
http status: 404, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7IaxPh0ttHTsJ4rVPPiQ9V?market=NL:
 Non existing id: 'spotify:track:7IaxPh0ttHTsJ4rVPPiQ9V', reason: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\Dirkv\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\SelfStudy\Python\Music Bot\music_bot.py", line 38, in <module>
    track = sp.track(url, 'NL')
```

Comment: Can you please add the full error message as text in your question?

Comment: that may because an exception occured with another type, and you are just catching SpotifyException, not that one

Comment: @hessam_kk I've tried catching Exception instead of SpotifyException and the problem persisted.

Comment: @jakub Done! Does this help?

Comment: This is still not a [mre] so it will be quite hard to help

Comment: Maybe the exception is happening in a different line of code. Can you try making a reproducible example that users here can copy and paste and run? That will probably help you narrow down the error too.

Comment: @jakub I can but then they'd need to set up a Spotify developer account too and configure the app settings. Not sure if people would go through that much effort to help me out

Comment: Someone would :)

Comment: @Dirk i posted answer, if it helps, please dont forget to approve my solution

Comment: Go and change your client secret immediately. You've posted it publicly on the internet.

Comment: @Dirk - like others have said, CHANGE YOUR CLIENT SECRET NOW. be careful not to post private credentials publicly.

Comment: Oh whoops, you're right, thanks a lot. I didn't really think to hide anything cause I literally only use it for this self study thing but in principle I understand why it should never be public.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import errors from **spotipy** not from **sp**

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="...",
                                               client_secret="...",
                                               redirect_uri="http://localhost/",
                                               scope="playlist-modify-public",
                                               requests_timeout=5))

try:
    track = sp.track('7IaxPh0ttHTsJ4rVPPiQ9V', 'NL')
except spotipy.SpotifyException :
    x = 0
except spotipy.SpotifyOauthError:
    print("SpotifyOauthError")
```

**NOTE :**

DO NOT post your **client_id** or **client_secret**   for your own safety

Comment: Did this fix the problem for you? Because for me it persists unfortunately. Also, wouldn't a generic Exception catch have caught that exception?

Comment: i also thought that `except Exception` would catch the error, because `spotipy.SpotifyException` [subclasses `Exception`](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/9a627e88f422927822ce39ae9919cc7ab9813dde/spotipy/exceptions.py#L1) and [so does `spotipy.SpotifyOauthError`](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/9a627e88f422927822ce39ae9919cc7ab9813dde/spotipy/oauth2.py#L32)

Comment: So were you able to reproduce the error I had and was it fixed by importing the errors from spotipy instead of sp? Because the solution didn't fix the issue for me